# Bug causes that nothing is shown on Konva.js stage only from time to time. What to do?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I have a very strange behaviour of my script: only from time to time (seldom 3-4 times at one time right after each other, but more likely every 7th to 150th trial) the skript loads, but I only see a white canvas and get the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getParent' of
>   undefinedKonva.Util.addMethods.add @ konva.min.js:44draw @
>   floorplansurvey.php:950(anonymous function) @
>   floorplansurvey.php:985images.(anonymous function).onload @
>   floorplansurvey.php:390

On reload it often works again...
I just have no idea at all what is happening here, the bug can't be forced/reproduced, I thank you so much, if you have anything you can help me with. Even a strategy for a clearer analysis would be helpful, sorry for being that unspecific and the long code

edit: I've made a jsfiddle under:
https://jsfiddle.net/17548hmv/1/

run it several times, until the error occures
these are the code snippets at:

> @ floorplansurvey.php:390:

```
function loadImages(sources, draw) {
    //window.location.reload(true);
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    // get num of sources
    for(var src in sources) {
        numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
        images[src] = new Image();
        images[src].onload = function() {
            if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                draw(images);
            }
        };
        images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
    delete (loadedImages);
    delete (numImages);
};
```

> @ floorplansurvey.php:985images.(anonymous function).onload:

```
loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    draw(images);
});
```

> @ floorplansurvey.php:950(anonymous function):

```
bglayer.add(plan);
```

> @ konva.min.js:44draw:
>   I dont understand this one myself

```
   add:function(t)
    {if(arguments.length>1)
    {for(var e=0;e<arguments.length;e++)
    this.add(arguments[e]);
    return this}if(t.getParent())return t.moveTo(this),this;
    var n=this.children;
    return
```

Var sources is defined like:

```
var sources = {

    Cd: './graphics/Cd.png',
    Cu: './graphics/Cu.png',
    Ca: './graphics/Ca.png',
    Cs: './graphics/Cs.png',
    Cc: './graphics/Cc.png',

    Ed: './graphics/Ed.png',
    Eu: './graphics/Eu.png',
    Ea: './graphics/Ea.png',
    Es: './graphics/Es.png',
    Ec: './graphics/Ec.png',

    Hd: './graphics/Hd.png',
    Hu: './graphics/Hu.png',
```

...and so on

and this is the function draw:

```
function draw(images) {
for (i=0, len=showdatax.length; i<=len-1; i++)
    {
        //window.location.reload(true);
    var gridcell = new Konva.Rect({
        x: parseInt((imagesizeX - showdatax[i])*scalar-(gridcellsize/2)),
        y: parseInt((imagesizeY - showdatay[i])*scalar-(gridcellsize/2)),
        offset: [0, 0],
        width: gridcellsize,
        height: gridcellsize,
        //fill: 'white',
        //stroke: 'grey',
        //strokeWidth: 2,
        draggable: false,
        id: showdatav[i]
    });
          gridlayer.add(gridcell);
    }
//defaultsettiongs
var init = new Array();
init['x'] = new Array();
init['y'] = new Array();

        init['x']['c'] = 0*scalar;
        init['y']['c'] = 170*scalar; 
        init['x']['e'] = 0*scalar;
        init['y']['e'] = 320*scalar; 
        init['x']['h'] = 0*scalar;
        init['y']['h'] = 470*scalar; 
        init['x']['l'] = 0*scalar;
        init['y']['l'] = 620*scalar; 
        init['x']['s'] = 0*scalar;
        init['y']['s'] = 770*scalar; 
        init['x']['w'] = 0*scalar;
        init['y']['w'] = 920*scalar; var step = 0;
var count = new Array (
'c','e','h','l','s','w');

        count['c'] = 0;

        count['e'] = 0;

        count['h'] = 0;

        count['l'] = 0;

        count['s'] = 0;

        count['w'] = 0;
    var starttime = new Date();
var loghistory = '';
//drag event functions
function mouseoverbox (box,active)
{
    writeMessage('Click and hold the left mouse button and pull this activity icon to the floorplan.');
    box.setFillPatternImage(active);
    box.shadowColor('blue');
    box.moveTo(templayer);
    badgelayer.draw();
    templayer.draw();
}
function dragstarttouchstartbox (box,pos,kind)
{
    //count[kind]++;
    writeMessage('dragstart' + count[kind]);
    var boxx = box.x;
    box.x(pos.x-1.5*gridcellsize);
    var boxy = box.y;
    box.y(pos.y-1.5*gridcellsize);
    var boxrshadowoffsetx = box.shadowOffset();
    box.shadowOffset({x:0.25*gridcellsize,y:0.25*gridcellsize});
    box.moveTo(templayer);
    badgelayer.draw();
    templayer.draw();
}
function dragmovebox (box,pos,kind,success,active,caution)
{
    writeMessage('Your outside of the floorplan. Dropping the activity icon will reset it to its initial position.');
    box.moveTo(templayer);
    var boxx = box.x;
    box.x(pos.x-1.5*gridcellsize);
    var boxy = box.y;
    box.y(pos.y-1.5*gridcellsize);
    var shape = gridlayer.getIntersection(pos);
    if (shape)
    {
        if (!badgelayer.getIntersection(pos))
        {
            writeMessage('Release the mouse button to place this activity icon on position (' + shape.x() + '|' + shape.y() + ')');
            box.x(shape.x()-gridcellsize);
            box.y(shape.y()-gridcellsize);
            box.setFillPatternImage(success);
            box.shadowColor('green');
            badgelayer.draw();
        }
        else
        {
            writeMessage('Position (' + shape.x() + '|' + shape.y() + ') is in use!!! Can\'t allocate second activiy icon here.');
            var boxx = box.x;
            box.x(pos.x-1.5*gridcellsize);
            var boxy = box.y;
            box.y(pos.y-1.5*gridcellsize);
            box.setFillPatternImage(caution);
            box.shadowColor('red');
            badgelayer.draw();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        box.setFillPatternImage(active);
        box.shadowColor('blue');
        templayer.draw();
        badgelayer.draw();
    }
}
function dragendtouchendbox (box,pos,kind,caution,defaultimage)
{
    var shape = gridlayer.getIntersection(pos);
    box.moveTo(badgelayer);
    templayer.draw();
    if (shape && !(badgelayer.getIntersection(pos)))
    {
        writeMessage('Activity icon successfully placed at position (' + shape.x() + '|' + shape.y() + ').');
        box.shadowOffset({x:0,y:0});
        box.shadowColor('green');
    }
    else
    {
        box.shadowColor('red');
        box.setFillPatternImage(caution);
        badgelayer.draw();
        var fromouttween = new Konva.Tween
        ({
            node: box,
            x: init['x'][kind]+imagesizeX*scalar+ gridcellsize,
            y: init['y'][kind],
            easing: Konva.Easings['EaseOut'],
            duration: 0.3
        });
        if (!shape)
        {
            writeMessage('Please drop the activity icons inside the floorplan.');
        }
        else if (badgelayer.getIntersection(pos))
        {
            writeMessage('Please don\'t drop the activity icons onto a used place.');
        }
        fromouttween.play();
        box.shadowColor('black');
        box.setFillPatternImage(defaultimage);
        box.shadowOffset({x:0,y:0});
        badgelayer.draw();
        pos.x=-100;
        pos.y=-100;
    }
    count['kind']++;
    step++;
    writeResultToForm(pos,count,kind,step,loghistory,starttime);
    badgelayer.draw();
    templayer.draw();
    //writeMessage('dragend');
}
function mouseoutbox (box,defaultimage)
{
    box.setFillPatternImage(defaultimage);
    box.moveTo(badgelayer);
    box.shadowColor('black');
    if (!validateForm(false))
    {
        writeMessage('There are still activity icons left to place.');
    }
    else
    {
        writeMessage('All activity icons are placed successfully. You can click "continue" now or change your placements.');
    }
    badgelayer.draw();
    templayer.draw();
}
function alertbox (box,caution)
{
    box.setFillPatternImage(caution);
    box.shadowcolor('red');
    badgelayer.draw;
}

//cbox and text
    var textc = new Konva.Text({
        x: init['x']['c']+imagesizeX*scalar+gridcellsize*5,
        y: init['y']['c']+gridcellsize,
        text: 'Cooking',
        align: 'left',
        width: badgetextwidth
    });
    var boxc = new Konva.Rect({
        x: init['x']['c']+imagesizeX*scalar+gridcellsize,
        y: init['y']['c'],
        offset: [0, 0],
        width: 3*gridcellsize,
        height: 3*gridcellsize,
        fillPatternImage: images.Cd,
        fillPatternScaleX: scalar,
        fillPatternScaleY: scalar,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true,
        cornerRadius: gridcellsize/2,
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowBlur: 10,
        shadowOffset: {x : 0, y : 0},
        shadowOpacity: 0.5
    });
    var boxcd = new Konva.Rect({
        x: init['x']['c']+imagesizeX*scalar+gridcellsize,
        y: init['y']['c'],
        offset: [0, 0],
        width: 3*gridcellsize,
        height: 3*gridcellsize,
        fillPatternImage: images.Cu,
        fillPatternScaleX: scalar,
        fillPatternScaleY: scalar,
        stroke: 'grey',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        draggable: false,
        cornerRadius: gridcellsize/2,
    });
    boxc.on('mouseover ', function() {
        mouseoverbox (this,images.Ca);
        });
    boxc.on('dragstart', function() {
        var pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
        dragstarttouchstartbox (this,pos,'c');
    });
    boxc.on('dragmove', function () {
        var pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
        dragmovebox(this,pos,'c',images.Cs,images.Ca,images.Cc);
    });
    boxc.on('dragend', function() {
        var pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
        dragendtouchendbox (this,pos,'c',images.Cc,images.Cd);
    });
    boxc.on('mouseout ', function() {
        mouseoutbox (this,images.Cd)
    });
    boxc.on('foo', function() {
        alertbox (this,images.Cd)
    });
//ebox and text
    var texte = new Konva.Text({
        x: init['x']['e']+imagesizeX*scalar+gridcellsize*5,


...and so on for all the boxes addes here (5 times as long):


        defaultlayer.add(boxcd);
        badgelayer.add(boxc);
        defaultlayer.add(textc);

        defaultlayer.add(boxed);
        badgelayer.add(boxe);
        defaultlayer.add(texte);

        defaultlayer.add(boxhd);
        badgelayer.add(boxh);
        defaultlayer.add(texth);

        defaultlayer.add(boxld);
        badgelayer.add(boxl);
        defaultlayer.add(textl);

        defaultlayer.add(boxsd);
        badgelayer.add(boxs);
        defaultlayer.add(texts);

        defaultlayer.add(boxwd);
        badgelayer.add(boxw);
        defaultlayer.add(textw);
        stage.add(bglayer);
    stage.add(gridlayer);
    stage.add(defaultlayer);
    stage.add(badgelayer);
    stage.add(templayer);
}
```

Comment: It is because in your code

    "bglayer.add(plan);"

`plan` object is `undefined` sometimes.

It is hard to say way your `plan` is undefined. Demo can help.

Comment: do you mean a jsfiddle? I've edited my question and added one... https://jsfiddle.net/17548hmv/1/

Comment: after asking a friend I found a solution, I'll explain it tomorrow, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, sorry that it took me so long:

the solution wasn't that easy to find. I found that the script was loaded asynchronously and the png wasn't yet available by using chromes timeline analysis. so i went to my code and had to distinguish between the things, that really should be in the draw function and which not. i added the plan to the array of images (sources) that is loaded (src= ...) before executing draw() and then added

```
sources.onload= loadImages(sources, function(images) {
    draw(images);
});
```

at the end of my file... no it works without any problem. konva.js had nothing to do with it and is up to now (I'm almost ready) like designed for my project

thanks for the tip @lavrton, it took me on the right way

Answer (score 1):

and you can just put like this:

```
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.src = 'http://localhost:8000/plugins/kamiyar/logo.png';

imageObj.onload = function() {

    var img = new Konva.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 200 / 2,
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 137 / 2,
        width: 200,
        height: 137,
        draggable: true,
        stroke: 'blue',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        dash: [1,5],
        strokeEnabled: false
    });

    layer.add(img);

    layer.draw();
};
```

sorry for my bad English ;)